# How to run a bash script from github?

Tags: bash

This question might be silly, and I think it is something so basic that I can't even find the solution because it might be obvious to everyone.

Here's the thing:

I want to download a file from mega.nz using bash.
I found this bash script on github: https://github.com/tonikelope/megadown/blob/master/megadown

I don´t know how to run this

Tried:
Copy-pasting the file to a file called "megadown.sh" and then running:

```
$ bash megadown.sh 'https://mega.nz/#F!BwQy2IAS!AwWpbCPzgLf_5jyj76q7qw'
```

this returns:

```
Reading link metadata...

Oooops, something went bad. EXIT CODE (3)
```

Which tells me that at least the code is running, but I don't know if I am doing it correctly.
This is better than my previous attempt `$ megadown 'URL'` (as the documentation suggested), which resulted in "`command not found`"

Comment: Run `bash megadown.sh`, and it'll show the help message

Comment: mI did, that help message lists all the options for the "megadown" command. But when I run that command it is not found. I guess I have to do some sort of installation. I normally install commands using yum. But I don't know how with this one. I feel }i am just missing something very basic

Comment: You should be running the "megadown command" as `bash megadown.sh`

Comment: apparently, the package could be installed using "yum install megadown", then I ran "megadl 'URL' ".

Comment: Should I modify the post to put the solution? I am new to this

Comment: No, solutions go in the "Answer" section

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have installed the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl curl pv jq
```

Then try running this command:

```
bash megadown.sh -o FILE_NAME "LINK"
```

It will download the file specified by the URL to a file called FILE_NAME.